# asp.net membership - let admin users manage the site in terms of roles

Tags: asp.net, membership, entitlements

is there a way i can let the admin users of my site manage roles of other users.  I see the asp.net membership tool but that seems to be just for developers of the site.  i want a situation where i can give one user admin role and let him manage all of the other role details of the other users so they dont have to come back to me for entitlement changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the ASP.net membership provider and Role manager provide APIs which make it very simple to roll you own management app.

[Membership API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx#paght000022_membershipapis)

[Role Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998314.aspx#paght000013_step3)

Comment: thanks. .  i just figured someone would have published out a basic web gui on top of this as a sample temple.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll have to write it yourself or buy a component. The default Membership provider has a well documented API so it shouldn't be too difficult if you just want to allow users to manage roles.